# Safety of custom SQL locking scheme

Tags: sql, concurrency

I have the following SQL table, called MyTable:

```
--------------------------------------------------
| ID | ReaderIn | WriterIn | .. Other columns .. |
--------------------------------------------------
| .. |   ...    |   ...    |      ......         |
--------------------------------------------------
```

Now client A (a reader) does the following

```
do {
   Update MyTable Set ReaderIn=1 WHERE WriterIn=0 AND ID=1
} while (NumberOfAffectedRows == 0)
// Important Note: NumberOfAffectedRows returns the number of matched rows, i.e. those for which the where
// conditions were satisfied, not the number of rows actually updated

// Enter critical path..
```

Client B (a writer) does the following

```
Update MyTable Set WriterIn=1 Where ID=1
do {
   Select ReaderIn As Locked From MyTable Where ID=1
} while (Locked == 1)

// Enter critical path
```

As an explanation, client B (the writer) makes it's presence known, setting WriterIn to 1, so that future readers will keep spinning on their loop without entering the critical path (since WriterIn=1, the NumberOfAffectedRows will be 0). Now B will wait for any possible readers that arrived before her to end their job, so she can take over. Assume that readers that entered their critical path before B arrived, will somehow set ReaderIn to 0 when ALL of them are done.

Now i am concerned if there is a possibility for both A and B to enter their critical path at the same time. For example, if A arrives first and sees a WriterIn value of 0, but B is fast enough to set WriterIn to 1 and read ReaderIn with a value of 0, before A was able to set it to 1. Is that possible to happen?

Don't bother about concurrent writers.

In case it matters, my database server is MariaDB-10.4.10.

Comment: "but B is fast enough" - You answered your own question. Never rely on speed to ensure locking.

Comment: @nicomp Can't i have a guarantee that A's update query won't be splitted in steps with other things happening in between the execution of those steps?

Comment: Only if you code it that way, and I don't see that in your p-code. You can add logic to make a statement or set of statements atomic. And by doing that you are no longer speed-dependent.

Comment: If reader goes in first, writer locks the row and busy-waits for the reader to release it. The protocol as it is written supports only one reader/writer. If there are multiple readers, the first reader unlocking will release it for all readers.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Yeah, this is true. My use case scenario needs only one reader/writer indeed. That's because if multiple readers enter the critical path, only one of them will do something useful. The rest will detect that more than one readers are active and will abort.

Comment: You could simply use `select for update`.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thank you, i didn't know about it. From what i 've seen i need to wrap it inside a transaction, like `begin; select for update; update; commit;`. Is that right?

Comment: Select for update, without a transaction, is meaningless because the transaction will then commit right after `select for update`, releasing the lock. To keep the lock across multiple operations, you have to have a transaction.